# Which local database is suitable for Windows 8 Store Apps?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I'am programming a `Windows 8 Store App` (Metro Design) with `C#` and `XAML` using `Visual Studio 2012`.

There is no need for a database server with multi user support etc.

I want to store my data in a local database and don't know which database is suitable for my needs.
Maybe `SQLite`? Or are there solutions that fits better for Windows Store Apps and integrates better in Visual Studio?

The app is kind of a calender and the database should store the user data that consists of the dates, tasks and so on.

Comment: This question is the number one result when searching Bing with the term _windows app local database_.   looks like the accepted answer is obsolete since sqlite is now supported.  Maybe answer should change?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I changed the accepted answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**SQLite** is the recommended database to be used for Win 8 Apps.
Links for implementing the same

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-SQLite-Asynchronously-b8372137

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e

Answer (score 18):

SQLite is supported for WinRT.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e

Comment: Do three packages corresponding to x86, x64 and ARM have to be submitted for every release of a Windows Store app if SQLite is used?  It does not seem to support "Any CPU".

Comment: Since SQLite is a native component, you cannot choose AnyCPU. However, you can create three (x86, x64 and ARM) app packages and upload to the Store at once for same the same app.

Answer (score 11):

Ok, this is a great question that I had to learn the hard way.  By default WinRT applications do NOT have access to, directly at least, to any type of database structure.  This means no Express, Compact, CE, SQLite etc.

There are three ways around this.  Do not use a database and instead use a local file structure where you store and retrieve your data.  XML works very nicely with this because you can maintain many of the same features a database would give you.

The second option is to use IndexedDB.  It is similar to a cookie style local storage model where files are saved in your apps local apps folder.

The third and final option is to use web services.  WinRT does have access to the internet which means you can write API and WebServices that can be called.  This does mean that you need to have a server running which is connected to a master database.  When your app needs data it calls your web service and obtains what it needs.

Overall, for the application you are describing the first option may best suite your needs.  Keep a local XML file in your apps folder and read/write from it.

Comment: OK I think i will do it the xml way.

Json.NET looks interesting [http://json.codeplex.com/](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: What happens if the objects got changed in future versions of my app from which the json are serialized? Am I still able to deserialize an old json file to a newer data object?

Comment: SQLite is supported and there is an extension SQLite for Windows Runtime

Comment: You should make it clear though that even though for example SQLite is not available from the OS, it is easy to link in to your app.

Comment: I asked a question about doing the same thing in C++ and quite inexplicably it was marked as a duplicate of this question.  My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500763/using-a-database-for-a-windows-8-store-app-using-c

Comment: Using SQLite's WinRT interface using C++/CX is not exactly a delight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309508/using-sqlite-winrt-from-a-c-windows-store-app

Answer (score 2):

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500763/using-a-database-for-a-windows-8-store-app-using-c) was marked as a duplicate of this question (although it was about C++ not C#). I thought I should still post my findings here.  C++ apps have another alternative:

[Extensible Storage Engine (ESE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269259%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx)

The list of all such API available for Store apps can be found on [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205753.aspx) under the section Jet.

Answer (score 1):

As one of variant:

Devart LinqConnect for Metro – a fully-functional high-performance ORM solution for developing Windows Store applications using either of LINQ or ADO.NET to access data.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/A-Simple-Windows-Store-85f29843#content

or next link can be usefull to

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18417.windows-store-app-with-a-sqlite-database.aspx