# How to use openDatabase or something similar in Windows Store app?

Tags: windows-8, cordova, windows-runtime, web-sql, windows-8.1

I have an existing PhoneGap (2.3.0) app with a lot of WebSQL in it. I try to port this to Windows Store App that means not Windows Phone 8 but Windows 8 (RT). I figure out that the basic feature window.openDatabase aka "WebSQL"for HTML5 isn't supported (PhoneGap docs: Abdroid, Blackberry, iOS not for MS).

Is there something similar in Windows RT?

best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which local database is suitable for Windows 8 Store Apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551091/which-local-database-is-suitable-for-windows-8-store-apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest Update: 
[New Cross Platform Cordova WebSQL plugin by MS Open Tech](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Interoperability/New-Cross-Platform-Cordova-plugin-by-MS-Open-Tech-WebSQL)

> Microsoft Open Technologies is publishing the new open source [WebSQL plugin](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-websql) for Apache Cordova and PhoneGap. This plugin allows developers to integrate a persistent SQL-based local storage solution in their Cordova apps using the exact same JavaScript code across Android, iOS, Windows Phone and Windows Store.

Answer (score 1):

For "database" functionality in a Windows 8 JavaScript app, two primary options come to mind:

1. [IndexedDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is native HTML5 capability but more of a key/value store,
2. [SQLLite](https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT), which is an in-memory relational database

Comment: I love the SQLLite-Component for WinRT!

Comment: IndexedDB is not available for Windows Phone. SQLite3-WinRT hasn't been updated in 2 years and is not compatible with Windows Phone 10. https://github.com/cloudcrypt/SQLite-Universal-WinJS-Component is a working one for Windows 10, built on Dave Risney's sample - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Universal-JavaScript-5728abdb